# AsyncData vs nuxtServerInit

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have some cookies set for auth user and user token.

After that on every `nuxtServerInit` I would check for same data in cookies and set them within store.

While I am using `asyncaData` within some pages, it seems like `asyncData` starts before `nuxtServerInit`...

```
async asyncData (context) {
    console.log(context.store.getters['auth/getToken'])
}
```

In this log I get `null` or whatever is pre-set within state:

```
export default () => ({
  user: null,
  token: null
})
```

I have store with modules where I have `auth module`with`index.js, actions.js, mutations.js, state.js and getters.js`

Within actions I have:

```
export const nuxtServerInit = ({ commit, getters }, { req, res }) => {
  commit('setToken', 'token')
  console.log('WORKING...')
}
```

When I refresh page with `asyncData` method I get error that `getToken` getter returns `null` instead of `'token'` string. And `console.log` from `nuxtServerInit` never fires.

From this [GitHub page](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2521) it says that `nuxtServerInit` should fire first and then after `asyncData`.

In my case it doesn't work....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`nuxtServerInit` is an action, and needs to be included in the actions export of your store file:

```
export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit = ({ commit, getters }, { req, res }) => {
    commit('setToken', 'token')
    console.log('WORKING...')
  }
}
```

Also note that this needs to be in the root module (index.js) of your store to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

`nuxtServerInit` action can only be defined in the primary module.

> If you are using the Modules mode of the Vuex store, only the primary
>   module (in `store/index.js`) will receive this action. You'll need to
>   chain your module actions from there.

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action

Comment: Well i made it work within module, so modules/auth/index.js that includes actions.js where I have nuxtserverinit

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your nuxtServerInit as async/await function.

```
export const async nuxtServerInit = ({ commit, getters }, { req, res }) => {
  await commit('setToken', 'token')
  console.log('WORKING...')
}
```

Comment: Or do similar with promise